# MsSQL FLOOR CEILING issue? Or is there an explanation about that?

Tags: sql, sql-server

anyone can try this in MsSQL:

```
select floor(4.7000000000000000000000000000000000000)+0.5
```

I get this result: 5  (!!) But should be 4.5 !?

Or try again with:

```
select floor(4.70 * 0.25000 * 0.2440 * 5.6325 * 3.0542 * 2.345 * 2.35 * 3.253 )+0.5
```

The result is 89!! But should be: 88.5  ?!

Is this an issue? Or is there an explanation about that?
(the same problem with `CEILING`)

Thank you all!

Comment: Weirdly enough, If you remove just one zero from the first exemple the anwers is `4.5` as expected.

Comment: `DECIMAL` precision. The rules for this are [complicated](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql). If you want something "simple", add "E" to one of your constants. Voila, now you get `FLOAT` calculations.

Comment: Yep. Basically the same as doing `select CAST(4 AS numeric(38,0)) + 0.5`

Comment: I will say that the documentation for `FLOOR` is quite misleading in that it states "Returns the same type as `numeric_expression`". It patently does not, unless you consider all `DECIMAL`s to be the same type regardless of scale or precision...

Comment: Yeah, it is a little confusing. If you create variables and set the correct data types, and hold the 4.70...0 and 0.5 in them, and then add them together, you will get the expected answer of 4.5.

Comment: Select cast(4.7 +0.5 as integer) third time the charm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation of `FLOOR`:

> `-- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse`
>
> `FLOOR ( numeric_expression )`
>
> ## Return Types
>
> Returns the same type as `numeric_expression`.

The problem with this is that it's not true. It preserves the base type, but in case of a `decimal` type, the scale is reduced to 0:

```
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(4.00, 'precision') AS [precision]
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(4.00, 'scale') AS scale,
```

Result: precision 3, scale 2.

```
SELECT 
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(FLOOR(4.00), 'precision') AS [precision],
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(FLOOR(4.00), 'scale') AS scale
```

Result: precision 3, scale 0. This becomes a problem as soon as your `decimal` hits the maximum precision:

```
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(4.7000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'precision') AS [precision]
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(4.7000000000000000000000000000000000000, 'scale') AS scale,
```

Precision 38, scale 37. But `FLOOR` turns this into precision 38, scale 0, and

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), 4) + 0.5
```

results in `5`, per the [rules for precision and scale when adding `decimal`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql): the result of this should be a `decimal(40, 1)`, but as that exceeds the maximum precision, the scale is reduced to preserve as many digits in front of the period as possible, giving us a `decimal(38, 0)` again: `5`.

Conversely, there's no problem with this:

```
SELECT 4.0000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.5
```

The result of this is a `DECIMAL(38, 37)`, which can hold `4.5000000000000000000000000000000000000` exactly.

The moral: be aware of this scale-eliminating aspect of `FLOOR` (and `CEILING`) and reduce the precision as necessary so the scale doesn't get reduced due to overflow:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(3, 0),  FLOOR(4.70 * 0.25000 * 0.2440 * 5.6325 * 3.0542 * 2.345 * 2.35 * 3.253)) + 0.5
```

Yields `88.5`.